# Getting list with deep=true in Backand

Tags: backand

I am having an issue getting relations backing using the deep parameter.

I'm using this url and am expecting it to return my related objects but is not.

`url: Backand.getApiUrl() +"/1/objects/blogs?deep=true"`,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the deep works only for specific item because of performance reasons. 
You should do /1/objects/blogs/1?deep=true

In general we suggest to query the blogs and from the client using promise to get the deep of each one.

If you must get it all at once, you can create server side on demand action, make the query and loop on the results while populating it with the deep. Because it runs on the server side it will be fast. here is a code example for the server-side action:

```
function backandCallback(userInput,dbRow,parameters,userProfile){
    var response=$http({
        method: "GET",
        url: CONSTS.apiUrl+"/1/objects/blogs",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": userProfile.token
        }
    });
    var mapping=response.data.map(function(item){
        var object=item;
        var user=$http({
            method: "GET",
            url: CONSTS.apiUrl+"/1/objects/users/"+item.author,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": userProfile.token
            }
        });
    object.author_obj=user;
    return object;
    })
    return mapping;
}
```